# Get all elements in a NodeCollections

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an html file :

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
<div></div>
<div class="Clearfix">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<span></span><span class="time">Time</span>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="Clearfix">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<span></span><span class="time">Time1</span>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="Clearfix">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<span></span><span class="time">Time2</span>
</div><div></div>
<div class="Clearfix">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<span></span><span class="time">Time3</span>
</div>
```

I'm using the c# code below to get all the `times` items :

```
var node_1 = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='form-wrapper']").First();
var ITEM = node_1.SelectNodes("//div[@class='clearfix']");
for (int Node = 0; Node < ITEM.Count; Node++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ITEM[Node].SelectNodes("//span[@class='time']")[1].InnerText.Trim());
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I'm taking the First() "Form-wrapper" since they're many .

I tried to use this too :

```
foreach (var Node in node_1.SelectNodes("//div[@class='clearfix']"))
{
 //
}
```

**Issue is** : as you can see I have 4 `Clearfix` Classes so i need to get the result :

```
Time
Time1
Time2
Time3
```

but for some reasons i only get :

```
Time
Time
Time
Time
```

Answer (score 2):

1. When you are querying over some node you don't need `//` at the beginning, if you are adding it query will be executed over whole document.
2. You need to take first node after selecting, so you need to take node with index `0` not `1`

This 2 points will solve your problem, but there are some improvements you can do

1. Instead of `SelecNodes().First()` you can user `SelectSingleNode()`
2. If you don't need any information about parent nodes you can directly query 
   for child nodes - `htmlDocument.SelectNodes("\\span[@class='time']")` will do all the work