# c# foreach in NodesCollections

Tags: c#, html

i have this html

```
            <div class="form-wrapper">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="time-wrapper col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="text-left col-md-6 cols-sm-12">
                <input type="radio" id="flight-return-1" name="flight-return"  data-default-meal="X">
                <div class="">
                  <div class="date pad-left-large-md no-padding-left-xs white-space-nowrap">Za. 06 May. 2017</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flight date text-right-md text-left-xs col-md-6 cols-sm-12 pad-right-large">
                      <span>
                      bet                      </span>
                      <span class="time">
                                                  12:10                                              </span>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="time-wrapper col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="flight date text-md-left text-sm-right no-padding-left col-md-7 cols-sm-12">
                        <span class="time">
                                                      14:25                                                  </span>
                        <span>
                        zeb                        </span>
              </div>
              <div class="price-wrapper col-md-5 cols-sm-12">
                                  <div class="price text-right white-space-nowrap">
                                        <span class="currency symbol">â‚¬</span> <span class="integer-part">69</span><span class="decimal-part">,99</span>                                      </div>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Please note that i have multiples `<div class="row">`inside one  .
i want to get all the data there 
i'm using this c# code :

```
    var node_1 = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='form-wrapper']").First();
    var ITEM = node_1.SelectNodes("//div[@class='clearfix']");
    foreach (var Node in node_1.SelectNodes("//div[@class='clearfix']"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Node.SelectNodes("//span[@class='time']")[1].InnerText.Trim());
    }
```

I'm only trying to get all the times (there is like 4 class(clearfix) )
so i'm expecting dates like :

```
14:25
18:25
17:50
13:20
```

but for some reasons i only get :

```
14:25
14:25
14:25
14:25
```

it keeps repeating this i m stuck at this

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Htmlagility get all elements in a NodeCollections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573640/c-sharp-htmlagility-get-all-elements-in-a-nodecollections)

Comment: @RubenVardanyan no i tried it its doesnt work i get null references exceptions

Comment: As I mentioned in previous qustion You have wrong index query and getting selected node with wrong index, should be `0` instead of `1`. You need to use this code to get what you want `Console.WriteLine(Node.SelectNodes("span[@class='time']")[0].InnerText.Trim());`

Comment: @RubenVardanyan that isn't the actual problem. the double forward slash means a global search in XPATH. Even though OP has applied it to the Node variable in a loop, the search is being performed in the whole document because of the double forward slash (I've had this issue before)

Comment: @Joon yes, You are right. I mentioned about that in the previous question about this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573640/c-sharp-htmlagility-get-all-elements-in-a-nodecollections

Comment: @RubenVardanyan just clicked through and upvoted you on the other question for answering OP already ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The double forward slash in the XPATH of your Console.WriteLine statement ("//span[....") is running out of your current node context and returning the first instance in the whole document that matches your XPATH.

Try to make your second XPATH relative  (best way is to debug the code and examine what was returned into the Node variable in the loop)

You could also just iterate the spans directly:

```
foreach (var spanNode in node_1.SelectNodes("//span[@class='time']"))
{
     Console.WriteLine(spanNode.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

Comment: it works but now for some reasons i get alot of duplicated results

Comment: `var node_1 = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='form-wrapper']").First();
            foreach (var Node in node_1.SelectNodes("label/div[@class='clearfix']"))
            {
                foreach (var item in Node.SelectNodes("//span[@class='time']")){
                    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
                }
            }` when i checked the count i found that the counts of nodes its exactly the counts of times but even tho it writes duplicated times

Comment: @GretaPorretta you have a loop inside a loop, so the inner one (which prints all time span contents) is running 4 times for every outer loop. You are probably seeing 16 lines instead of 4 right? Change the code so that there is only one foreach loop, like this: var node_1 = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='form-wrapper']")‌​.First(); foreach (var item in Node.SelectNodes("//span[@class='time']")){ Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText); }

Answer (score 0):

you are passing index statically this will be the issue

```
 Node.SelectNodes("//span[@class='time']")[1].InnerText.Trim()//Here [1] you are passing statically
```